# How to figure which is the right cognito error

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-cognito

Lets say I want to create a library application and manage user subscriptions with AWS Cognito. I have the following user registered in my AWS Cognito user pool

```
 email: abc@abc.abc
 psw: 123456
```

And I wish to populate different errors such as

- you're not registered - for users who didn't sign up to our library service
- login data is incorrect - if the user is registered but has a typo in username or password
- please renew subscription -if the subscription ended.

**The problem I'm facing** - it seems that AWS cognito returns `NotAuthorizedException` when the user didn't signup as well as when he did and just had a typo

Is there a way to distinct between these two use cases?
according to AWS(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminListUserAuthEvents.html) there are different errors for these scenarios `NotAuthorizedException`, `InvalidParameterException`, `UserNotFoundException` but for some reason I only get one `NotAuthorizedException`

Can someone advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took some time to figure this out.
As of Feb 2021 when creating user pools `PreventUserExistenceErrors` is set to `ENABLED` this results showing all errors as a generic `NotAuthorizedException`error no matter the reason.

If we want to receive different errors for when the user does not exist and when the user has a typo mistake then you have to change `PreventUserExistenceErrors` to `LEGACY`
this is how to:

1. open Cognito dashboard
2. select your user pool
3. go to AppClient --> Show Details -->Security configuration -->Prevent User Existence Errors change to `Legacy` and save.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the steps do this in the web interface! The documentation only explains how to do it through CloudFormation. This saved my day.

Comment: I tried to set it `LEGACY` but it still returns `NotAuthorizedException`. Do you guys have any suggestions?